# Boost Asio UDP Daytime Server Async receive

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, udp, boost-asio

I've been learning boost asio recently, especially UDP.  I am familiar with the basics, but had a question regarding how UDP handles incoming messages.  In the tutorial (see source code here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tutdaytime6/src.html), the UDP server operates something like (very pseudo-code):

```
startReceive(){
    async_receive(boost::bind(handler),...other params);
}

handler(){
    doStuffToDataReceived();
    startReceive(); //start the receiving process over again to allow it to receive more data
}
```

My question is, if data arrives to the server during the time that it is in "doStuffToDataReceived()", before it startReceives over again, does that data get lost, or does it sit there and wait for startReceive to happen again and then is immediately retrieved?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UDP stack has a buffer, so the data in the above example wouldn't get lost.

Note however, that UDP is allowed to drop packets under various circumstances. So, as the throughput of the UDP server grows, the timings of `doStuffToDataReceived` might become much more critical.

Comment: Can you be more specific as to the circumstances under which it is allowed to drop packets?

Comment: @jekelija For instance, when the application is unable to process the packets as fast as they arrive. Or when a network can't cope with the throughput demands. In general: http://bit.ly/1b9XaRp

Comment: @jekelija: As the protocol is specified as being unreliable, I do not believe the specification provides specific circumstances.  The guidelines suggest that applications using UDP should be able to handle loss, duplicate, or out-of-order datagrams.